# Comparison and understanding of different version of DDQN?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn, deep-rl

There are several version of DDQN floating around. Sutton gives one that is a simple symmetric random update of the two Q functions. I think other papers (Silver paper for example) use a kind of delayed and split update rule.

Is there anything systematic describing the properties of the bias corrections and their respective advantages?

Comment: Double Q-learning was proposed by van Hasselt not Sutton neither Silver, there is an original Double Q-learning [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3964-double-q-learning.pdf) by van Hasselt that presents the algorithm for tabular case and there is also [adaptation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06461.pdf) of that algorithm for function approximation case